# How to make responsive design for different size images?

Tags: html, css

I am getting images of different size in my api response. I have created a table in my html page and I am displaying this images in that table.
I am getting 4 images.
So I have set width of 
table as 100%,
tr as 100%,
td as 25%,
image as 100%.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img/></td>
        <td><img/></td>
        <td>>img/></td>
        <td><img/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I am decreasing the size of the window the width of td is responsing but the height remains same.
How can I make td's height (and hence image's height as well) responsive?

Comment: Using tables is not a responsive design approach. Nothing in your question suggests you are using an actual responsive design

Comment: So what I should be doing instead?

Comment: Try dropping the idea of using the tables. We are in 2k14.

Comment: Wish I could, deadline tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bootstrap for responsive images. Link - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

You just have to add the plugins and add above class `img-responsive` to the image tag and thats it.

Since you can't add bootstrap to your project, you can simply add the `class` in your `css file` and apply this `class` to your `img tag`. What that class does is following. This this code -

```
.img-responsive {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Its a part of my coursework and we are not allowed to use bootstrap. :)

Comment: So you can see what that class `img-responsive` does. I guess you'll find something there.

Comment: My problem here is I need to use fix 25% width for td.
Using this code I am getting blank area in my td around the image.

Comment: why you have set `display:block` to image. Images behaves both as `block` and `inline-block`. This will not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your custom class named "img-responsive" and add these properties to it ?

```
.img-responsive {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

There is no need to use the library when you have the code that the library uses !

Comment: My problem here is I need to use fix 25% width for td. Using this code I am getting blank area in my td around the image
Images are not filling up the entire height of TD, when I use this code.